# How do I compile glib using android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, glib

There are several repositories with ports of glib to the android platform, how do I compile those libraries using android NDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and for example with https://github.com/ieei/glib the following worked for me:

```
…/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I add the next line to Android.mk

```
TARGET_FORMAT_STRING_CFLAGS := -Wformat -Wno-error
```

and after that I compile the code using:

```
<android-ndk-path>/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=./Android.mk
```